# Calling Graphics.drawImage in the contructor of a JFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

So I'm trying to figure out how to work with JFrames and Graphics, and was just writing a small program for leaning purposes.  I ran into a problem.  I have the class `JFrameLeaning` that extends `JFrame`.  What I'm trying to do is have the window size itself for an Image it loads, then display the image.  The sizing works fine, but the image doesn't display, just an empty window.  I've looked at the documentation, but I can't figure out why the image doesn't display.  Sorry if this question is obvious.  Here is the class

```
//imports
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

// class to learn how to use JFrames
public class JFrameLearning extends JFrame{
    public BufferedImage tileset;
    public Graphics tilesetGraphics;

    // 0 argument constructor
    public JFrameLearning(){
        // load the tileset image
        try {
            tileset = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Mountain.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try {
            tilesetGraphics = tileset.getGraphics();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        this.setSize(tileset.getWidth(),tileset.getHeight());
        this.setVisible(true);
        tilesetGraphics.drawImage(tileset, 0, 0, tileset.getWidth(),    tileset.getHeight(), this);
    }// 0 argument constructor


}// class
```

Comment: So, you're drawing the image to itself then? Have you read any of the tutorials like [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) or [Performing Cusrom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) or [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I have not read some of those, no.  I will right now